# Elasticsearch - Get result summary by fields

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregate

```
{"name": "John", "district": 1, "light": 2},
{"name": "John", "district": 5, "light": 2},
{"name": "John", "district": 5, "light": 27},
{"name": "John", "district": 11, "light": 1},
{"name": "John", "district": 11, "light": 0},
{"name": "John", "district": 11, "light": 10},
{"name": "John", "district": 8, "light": 6},
{"name": "Mary", "district": 2, "light": 10},
{"name": "Nick", "district": 1, "light": 0},
{"name": "Bob", "district": 3, "light": 10},
{"name": "Kenny", "district": 1, "light": 8}
```

When searching by name field, how can i get a summary of the remaining fields by group count?

Example:

When searching by

```
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": {
        "value": "john"
      }
    }
  }
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "district": {
    11: 3, // value : the amount of matches
    5: 2,
    1: 1,
  },
  "light": {
    2: 2, // value : the amount of matches
    27: 1,
    10: 1,
    // etc..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a pair of terms aggregations:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name": {
        "value": "john"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_district": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "district"
      }
    },
    "by_light": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "light"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Question: is this a super mortal query?, can each agg be limited? (will that improve performance if i only request like top 3 of each field?)

Comment: super mortal meaning what? You can limit them with `size`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size The improvement in speed depends on many factors but setting a low size usually helps.